# Exclude child request of a transaction controller in aggregate report in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Have two question,

1. While executing the following command,

`./JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv C:\JMeterTool\Report\reportNEW.csv --input-jtl C:\JMeterTool\Report\Report.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport`

And Error I was getting,

```
  ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.AggregateReportGui
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: C:\JMeterTool\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.AggregateReportGui
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:237)
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:234)
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.getGUIObject(PluginsCMDWorker.java:230)
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.setPluginType(PluginsCMDWorker.java:73)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.ReporterTool.processParams(ReporterTool.java:102)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115)
```

I resolved this by installing `Synthesis Report`, building an automation system so to handle this exception want to install it via script. Is it `PluginManager.cmd install Synthesis Report`?

2. Now from the CSV report I want to exclude the child element call from the transaction controller, how to do it ?

Sample TestPlan:

[image]

Generated Report:

[image]

Want only `LaunchApplication` and `BookRoom` as `get call`,`get details` & `fill details` are child element of the transaction controller and have checked the `generate the parent sample`.

3. Also I want to add `70% and 75% line` to the report, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 question here,

1. Yes, for installing plugin in JMeter through CMDLine is,

   `PluginsManagerCMD <command> [<params>]` this is basic syntax.

   `PluginsManagerCMD jpgc-synthesis` for your plugin

   details are here [plugin manager document](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/#Installation)
2. Excluding subresult, you need to exclude the option of `save sub result` option.

   [image]
3. For including the 70th, 75th percentile, you need to do the following changes,
   For aggregate report, add the following lines in the `jmeter.properties` file located in the `/bin` directory.

   - `aggregate_rpt_pct1=70`
   - `aggregate_rpt_pct2=75`

Answer (score 2):

1. You can see what plugins can be installed by running `PluginsManagerCMD available` command. For the Synthesis Report it would be `PluginsManagerCMD jpgc-synthesis=2.2`. More information: [Plugins Manager from Command-Line](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)
2. It's not right approach because if you exclude them - JMeter won't properly calculate throughput and hits per second metrics. If they appear as separate entries in the report it's better to rename them:

   [image]

   In case you **really** want to remove them from the results file - add `jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false` to user.properties file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation). More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)
3. The percentiles are controllable via [special JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#aggregate_report_graph). There are 3 pre-defined percentiles, you cannot "add" anything but you can substitute any of them with your own line, if this is something want to do add the next lines to `user.properties` file

   ```
   aggregate_rpt_pct2=70
   aggregate_rpt_pct3=75
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up.